# Why is a DataSet loaded in C# with ReadXml empty?

Tags: c#, xml, dataset

I am using C# 4.5/Visual Studio 2012 to try to load an XML file to a DataSet.  I read the instructions here:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fx29c3yd.aspx

I am loading an XML file that looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>

<UnitTestDataSet xmlns="https://rebuildinghomes.codeplex.com/" 
        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
        xsi:schemaLocation="https://rebuildinghomes.codeplex.com/ UnitTestLoadData.xsd">
  <Person>
    <PersonId>1111</PersonId>
    <FirstName>Unit</FirstName>
    <LastName>Tester</LastName>
  </Person>
</UnitTestDataSet>
```

With a schema like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>

<xs:schema id="RebuildingUnitTestData"
            targetNamespace="https://rebuildinghomes.codeplex.com/"
            xmlns:u="https://rebuildinghomes.codeplex.com/"
            elementFormDefault="qualified"
            xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
            xmlns:msdata="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xml-msdata">
  <xs:complexType name="PersonType">
    <xs:sequence>
      <xs:element name="PersonId" type="xs:int"
                   minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" />
      <xs:element name="FirstName" type="xs:string"
                   minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" />
      <xs:element name="LastName" type="xs:string"
                   minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" />
    </xs:sequence>
  </xs:complexType>
</xs:schema>
```

Using the following C# code:

```
        //Load init/expected
        DataSet init = new DataSet();

        init.ReadXmlSchema("RebuildingModel/Data/UnitTestLoadData.xsd");

        init.ReadXml("RebuildingModel/Data/PersonUnitTest.xml", XmlReadMode.ReadSchema);
```

However, when I look at "init" in the debugger, the DataSet is empty.  What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I ran your code and it seems to work. What do you mean by the dataset is empty, that there isn't a table in the dataset?

Comment: Interesting, this does not work for me either. The table is only populated into the dataset when I change XmlReadMode to XmlReadMode.Auto in your example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally figured this out.

The schema now looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xs:schema id="UnitTestDataSet" xmlns="" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:msdata="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xml-msdata" xmlns:msprop="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xml-msprop">
  <xs:annotation>
    <xs:appinfo source="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xml-msdatasource">
      <DataSource DefaultConnectionIndex="0" FunctionsComponentName="QueriesTableAdapter" Modifier="AutoLayout, AnsiClass, Class, Public" SchemaSerializationMode="IncludeSchema" xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xml-msdatasource">
        <Connections />
        <Tables />
        <Sources />
      </DataSource>
    </xs:appinfo>
  </xs:annotation>
  <xs:element name="UnitTestDataSet" msdata:IsDataSet="true" msdata:UseCurrentLocale="true" msprop:Generator_DataSetName="UnitTestDataSet" msprop:Generator_UserDSName="UnitTestDataSet">
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:choice minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded">
        <xs:element name="Person" msprop:Generator_TableClassName="PersonDataTable" msprop:Generator_TableVarName="tablePerson" msprop:Generator_TablePropName="Person" msprop:Generator_RowDeletingName="PersonRowDeleting" msprop:Generator_RowChangingName="PersonRowChanging" msprop:Generator_RowEvHandlerName="PersonRowChangeEventHandler" msprop:Generator_RowDeletedName="PersonRowDeleted" msprop:Generator_UserTableName="Person" msprop:Generator_RowChangedName="PersonRowChanged" msprop:Generator_RowEvArgName="PersonRowChangeEvent" msprop:Generator_RowClassName="PersonRow">
          <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
              <xs:element name="PersonId" msprop:Generator_ColumnVarNameInTable="columnPersonId" msprop:Generator_ColumnPropNameInRow="PersonId" msprop:Generator_ColumnPropNameInTable="PersonIdColumn" msprop:Generator_UserColumnName="PersonId" type="xs:int" />
              <xs:element name="FirstName" msprop:Generator_ColumnVarNameInTable="columnFirstName" msprop:Generator_ColumnPropNameInRow="FirstName" msprop:Generator_ColumnPropNameInTable="FirstNameColumn" msprop:Generator_UserColumnName="FirstName" type="xs:string" />
              <xs:element name="LastName" msprop:Generator_ColumnVarNameInTable="columnLastName" msprop:Generator_ColumnPropNameInRow="LastName" msprop:Generator_ColumnPropNameInTable="LastNameColumn" msprop:Generator_UserColumnName="LastName" type="xs:string" />
              <xs:element name="HomePhoneNbr" msprop:Generator_ColumnVarNameInTable="columnHomePhoneNbr" msprop:Generator_ColumnPropNameInRow="HomePhoneNbr" msprop:Generator_ColumnPropNameInTable="HomePhoneNbrColumn" msprop:Generator_UserColumnName="HomePhoneNbr" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" />
              <xs:element name="CellPhoneNbr" msprop:Generator_ColumnVarNameInTable="columnCellPhoneNbr" msprop:Generator_ColumnPropNameInRow="CellPhoneNbr" msprop:Generator_ColumnPropNameInTable="CellPhoneNbrColumn" msprop:Generator_UserColumnName="CellPhoneNbr" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" />
              <xs:element name="StreetAddress" msprop:Generator_ColumnVarNameInTable="columnStreetAddress" msprop:Generator_ColumnPropNameInRow="StreetAddress" msprop:Generator_ColumnPropNameInTable="StreetAddressColumn" msprop:Generator_UserColumnName="StreetAddress" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" />
              <xs:element name="AptNbr" msprop:Generator_ColumnVarNameInTable="columnAptNbr" msprop:Generator_ColumnPropNameInRow="AptNbr" msprop:Generator_ColumnPropNameInTable="AptNbrColumn" msprop:Generator_UserColumnName="AptNbr" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" />
              <xs:element name="City" msprop:Generator_ColumnVarNameInTable="columnCity" msprop:Generator_ColumnPropNameInRow="City" msprop:Generator_ColumnPropNameInTable="CityColumn" msprop:Generator_UserColumnName="City" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" />
              <xs:element name="County" msprop:Generator_ColumnVarNameInTable="columnCounty" msprop:Generator_ColumnPropNameInRow="County" msprop:Generator_ColumnPropNameInTable="CountyColumn" msprop:Generator_UserColumnName="County" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" />
              <xs:element name="StateProvCd" msprop:Generator_ColumnVarNameInTable="columnStateProvCd" msprop:Generator_ColumnPropNameInRow="StateProvCd" msprop:Generator_ColumnPropNameInTable="StateProvCdColumn" msprop:Generator_UserColumnName="StateProvCd" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" />
              <xs:element name="PostalCode" msprop:Generator_ColumnVarNameInTable="columnPostalCode" msprop:Generator_ColumnPropNameInRow="PostalCode" msprop:Generator_ColumnPropNameInTable="PostalCodeColumn" msprop:Generator_UserColumnName="PostalCode" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" />
              <xs:element name="CountryCode" msprop:Generator_ColumnVarNameInTable="columnCountryCode" msprop:Generator_ColumnPropNameInRow="CountryCode" msprop:Generator_ColumnPropNameInTable="CountryCodeColumn" msprop:Generator_UserColumnName="CountryCode" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" />
              <xs:element name="NumberOfYearsAtAddr" msprop:Generator_ColumnVarNameInTable="columnNumberOfYearsAtAddr" msprop:Generator_ColumnPropNameInRow="NumberOfYearsAtAddr" msprop:Generator_ColumnPropNameInTable="NumberOfYearsAtAddrColumn" msprop:Generator_UserColumnName="NumberOfYearsAtAddr" type="xs:int" minOccurs="0" />
              <xs:element name="EmailAddress" msprop:Generator_ColumnVarNameInTable="columnEmailAddress" msprop:Generator_ColumnPropNameInRow="EmailAddress" msprop:Generator_ColumnPropNameInTable="EmailAddressColumn" msprop:Generator_UserColumnName="EmailAddress" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" />
              <xs:element name="GenderCode" msprop:Generator_ColumnVarNameInTable="columnGenderCode" msprop:Generator_ColumnPropNameInRow="GenderCode" msprop:Generator_ColumnPropNameInTable="GenderCodeColumn" msprop:Generator_UserColumnName="GenderCode" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" />
              <xs:element name="EthnicityCode" msprop:Generator_ColumnVarNameInTable="columnEthnicityCode" msprop:Generator_ColumnPropNameInRow="EthnicityCode" msprop:Generator_ColumnPropNameInTable="EthnicityCodeColumn" msprop:Generator_UserColumnName="EthnicityCode" type="xs:int" minOccurs="0" />
              <xs:element name="BirthDate" msprop:Generator_ColumnVarNameInTable="columnBirthDate" msprop:Generator_ColumnPropNameInRow="BirthDate" msprop:Generator_ColumnPropNameInTable="BirthDateColumn" msprop:Generator_UserColumnName="BirthDate" type="xs:date" minOccurs="0" />
              <xs:element name="ResidentStatus" msprop:Generator_ColumnVarNameInTable="columnResidentStatus" msprop:Generator_ColumnPropNameInRow="ResidentStatus" msprop:Generator_ColumnPropNameInTable="ResidentStatusColumn" msprop:Generator_UserColumnName="ResidentStatus" type="xs:int" minOccurs="0" />
            </xs:sequence>
          </xs:complexType>
        </xs:element>
      </xs:choice>
    </xs:complexType>
    <xs:unique name="Constraint1" msdata:PrimaryKey="true">
      <xs:selector xpath=".//Person" />
      <xs:field xpath="PersonId" />
    </xs:unique>
  </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

The big thing that changed, as you'll notice, is all of the extraneous junk that Visual Studio adds in.  Apparently, .NET needs some of this to load the data properly, most notably the primary key annotation.  So the moral of the story: if you're going to load a DataSet from XML, create a schema through Visual Studio or be prepared to run it through XSLT to add all this stuff, or the results will be unpredictable, at best.

Answer (score 1):

Sadly, your snippet of code seem to work on my machine.  Are you sure you're checking init **AFTER** the init.ReadXml() statement executes?

See my output from my Visual Studio immediate window below:

```
ds.Tables[0]
{Person}
    base {System.ComponentModel.MarshalByValueComponent}: {Person}
    CaseSensitive: false
    ChildRelations: {System.Data.DataRelationCollection.DataTableRelationCollection}
    Columns: {System.Data.DataColumnCollection}
    Constraints: {System.Data.ConstraintCollection}
    DataSet: {System.Data.DataSet}
    DefaultView: {System.Data.DataView}
    DisplayExpression: ""
    ExtendedProperties: Count = 0
    HasErrors: false
    IsInitialized: true
    Locale: {en-US}
    MinimumCapacity: 50
    Namespace: "https://rebuildinghomes.codeplex.com/"
    ParentRelations: {System.Data.DataRelationCollection.DataTableRelationCollection}
    Prefix: ""
    PrimaryKey: {System.Data.DataColumn[0]}
    RemotingFormat: Xml
    Rows: {System.Data.DataRowCollection}
    Site: null
    TableName: "Person"
ds.Tables[0].Rows
{System.Data.DataRowCollection}
    base {System.Data.InternalDataCollectionBase}: {System.Data.DataRowCollection}
    Count: 1
```

My DataSet is populated with a single table containing a single row as per your XML.

Comment: I'm absolutely sure.  I have an exception to check it, and it always gets thrown:

`init = new DataSet();

            init.ReadXmlSchema("RebuildingModel/Data/UnitTestLoadData.xsd");

            init.ReadXml("RebuildingModel/Data/PersonUnitTest.xml", XmlReadMode.ReadSchema);

            if (init.Tables.Count < 1)
                throw new Exception("Didn't load the unit test data!");`

Comment: Interesting fact.... if I remove the XmlReadMode.ReadSchema parameter, the DataSet is populated, but the only table in it is named "Table1".

Answer (score 0):

Could it be the space in the following:

```
xsi:schemaLocation="https://rebuildinghomes.codeplex.com/ UnitTestLoadData.xsd">
```

from your xml file?

Comment: xsi:schemaLocation requires that - Visual Studio correctly flags an error if you do not have a URI->URL mapping.

http://www.w3schools.com/schema/schema_schema.asp